# Ender 3 motors zero movement

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting

I’ve just bought an Ender 3 Pro (my first printer). I followed a video guide on YouTube and set everything up. I had to flash the latest firmware because my system wouldn’t boot.

Now I have zero movements in any of the X, Y, and Z motors. All my tolerances are correct, all is fastened as it should be and tightened, including the bearings and the belts. The system will not auto-home, it gives me a fail message and asks me to reset the printer. The motors will not move when I try them manually via the 0.1, 1, and 10 mm options. I have checked all of my connections and swapped cables around (X to Z and vice versa).

I am at a loss, and honestly so frustrated.

Comment: When you say it won't autohome, does it fail immediately, or does it try to move for a while and give up or does it move a little bit and then give up?

Comment: A printer should work out of the box and shouldn't require a firmware update to work. You should've notified the seller and let it be addressed by them. It is strongly advised to flash the official firmware version of the printer. At the moment it is unclear to troubleshoot if you have a hardware or software issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend attempting a reinstall of the default factory firmware. If you're getting zero function or movement from the printer and you have double checked connections it's highly likely this is purely a firmware issue of some kind that a reinstall could resolve.

As commented can you confirm that no matter the sources of the move command not a single motor moves or even tries to move? In the interest to rule out an issue other then the electronics and firmware.

Before going through the trouble and risk of a firmware update contacting the seller first likely would have been a better first option.